# Even distribution of percentile labels on x axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, quantile

Forgive my terminology, I'm not an expert at statistics or plotting!

Using Pandas, I am attempting to plot quantile data that is bucketed up to "5 9s". That is, for a given DataFrame 'df' that has a series 'foo' of unevenly distributed integer values:

```
q = df['foo'].quantile([.1, .2, .3, .4, .5, .6, .7, .8, .9, .99, .999, .9999, .99999, 1])
q.plot()
```

Results in a plot where the x-axis intervals between 0.9 and 1.0 are compressed:
[image]

Is there a way to evenly space the quantile buckets on the x-axis ?

Thanks!

Comment: One possibility is to set up a new variable that is a 1-1 mapping of quantile buckets, but counts from 1 to n where n is the number of buckets. produce the graph with this as the x axis, then add the quantiles as labels.

Comment: lmo, if you want to change this to an answer, I'll give you the credit - what you suggested worked. Thanks.

Comment: It's fine If you want to post your code as an answer. I'm a bit preoccupied at the moment. Just add a quick thanks for the suggestion or the like at the end. I'll give you an upvote if you let me know when you post it. Otherwise, I'll take a crack at it this weekend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking lmo's advice, here's the solution that works for me.

For a given dataframe 'df' that has a series 'A':

```
percentiles = [.1, .2, .3, .4, .5, .6, .7, .8, .9, .99, .999, .9999, .99999, 1.0]

pct = df['A'].quantile(percentiles)
xticks = range(0, len(percentiles), 1)
ax = pct.plot (xticks=xticks)
ax.set_xticklabels([str(p) for p in percentiles)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [`pd.qcut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.qcut.html)

***example***

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = np.sort(np.random.rand(1000))
b = a.repeat(np.arange(len(a)))
b += np.random.rand(len(b)) / 100
s = pd.Series(b)

s.hist()
```

[image]

***you want this***
use however many bins you want.  I used 20.  I also passed a labels parameter.  Without it, pandas will label with the edges of the where the cuts were made.

```
q = pd.qcut(s, 20, labels=range(20))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, my data is not distributed enough to avoid non-unique bin edges.  At any rate, I need the ability to show _N_ 9's precision above the 90th percentile. Perhaps I don't understand your response fully.